# Should a production site use HTML5 or XHTML1 Strict?

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm designing a small buiness's website, and I'm windering if I should use HTML5 or XHTML1. I know that HTML5 is more advanced, but it is still a changing spec, while XHTML1 is finalized, so there won't be any compatibility issues in the future. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 4.01 Strict is the best toy to play with. HTML 5 is not ready, and while it doesn't hurt to include some of its features to enhance your site, where they are supported in some browsers and don't cause others to fall over, it isn't worth investing too much time and effort when the spec could still change significantly.

Unless you know that no-one wanting to visit your site will be using any form of Internet Explorer (up to and including IE8), there's no point in worrying about XHTML. You can only serve it as XHTML, so you don't get any of the advantages of the X, you just end up having to jump through more hoops and run with messy code to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: I usually use serverside scripts to serve a page as HTML to IE and XHTML to everything else.

Comment: if any of your visitor using version less than IE 8 then you have to take care for use HTML5 there..if all visitors are using greater then IE 8 then you don't need to worry about using HTML5.. there won't be creating any problem there in future

Answer (score 1):

There is no big difference, html5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`) works correctly in all browsers and corresponds to transitional mode in old browsers. If you wonder should you use new semantic tags from html5 than I can say that there is a simple trick to make them works fine in all browsers.

Comment: "corresponds to transitional mode in old browsers" This is wrong, even if by "transitional mode" you mean "almost standards mode". It corresponds to standards mode.